# How to skip a header row in a csv file?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a csv file generated with headings on the first row and data on the rest. The file varies each time and I have to have all these values for further usage. I'm using File.ReadAllLines(path) but could ignore the header row. How to accomplish this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just start from the second line (`index 1 of returned string[]`)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This is better:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.txt").Skip(1); // this will return an IEnumerable<string>
File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.txt").Skip(1).ToArray(); // This will return an array of string (string[])
```

**OLD**

```
bool first = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    File.ReadLines(@"c:\test.txt").ToList().ForEach(c => 
    { 
        if (first) first = false;
        else sb.Append(c); 
    }
    );
```

string res = sb.ToString();

This will essentually skip the first line, Don't know if there is a better way to do it

Comment: Error: 'skip' is not a memebr of System.Array. I need to have these values for further iteration. Is there a any other way to skip the line?

Comment: add a using to: using System.Linq;